# How do i classify a signal by using LDA

Tags: c++, c, svm, lda

I am using LDA algorithm to classify a signal, how can i do that with multiple classes ? I have read some references but don't get the result.
I I've looked example code at [link](http://www.developerstation.org/2012/05/linear-discriminant-analysis-using.html)

but it doesn't have explicit classifier part for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use OpenCV to keep doing this.